# Growing array of primitives in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am learning Android and at the same time boosting my efficiency know-how. I am writing a password generator that generates a random password from a set of characters selected using specific rules. I have an array where I am planning to store the characters. The array begins at a size of X, which is the amount of possible character in all cases. I then add up to three times additional sets of characters to the array. Since I can't resize the array, I would have to copy and recreate it larger every time with a copy loop or ArrayCopy or similar.

Should I do that or switch to for example ArrayList? Sure, neither will in real life be problems as there will be about 70 characters in total, but I am interested in it as a practice.

Thanks to all.

pseudocode:

```
initialize array  
add first set  
if adding second set  
    add second set  
if adding third set  
    add third set  
if adding fourth set  
    add fourth set  
return array
```

Comment: I rarely use arrays - only when I know that the size will be constant and that I will need to get items by index. Usually lists (of different kind) are more suited to everyday tasks.

Comment: What you're doing is *sort of similar* to the inner workings of an `ArrayList`, so I'd recommend just using an `ArrayList`

Comment: What you described is exactly what ArrayList does internally. An ArrayList<String> has a String[] attribute with an initial size. Before adding an element the ArrayList test to see if there's still space for another object, if not it creates a new String[] with a larger size (like size+20) and copy the content from the original array to the new array. So your choice would be use the code available or recreate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch to the collection (like your mentioned [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)), because it will be significantly more efficient then creating a new array and copying the values for every insert (which you must do if you use an array because, as you noted, arrays are statically sized at creation).

The `ArrayList` Javadoc says (in part),

> Resizable-array implementation of the `List` interface. Implements all optional list operations, and permits all elements, including `null`. In addition to implementing the `List` interface, this class provides methods to manipulate the size of the array that is used internally to store the list.

Comment: How about the size? ArrayList doesn't take primitives, right? An Object is always larger than a primitive, if I have understood correctly. What would be the size difference between the partial arrays and a similar ArrayList?

Comment: You don't manage memory in Java, and most of the primitive wrapper types (that you'll get) use an instance cache pool.

Comment: *"You don't manage memory in Java"* - I suspect that attitude is taken by many, many Java devs. It's also wrong. Your practices can have a tremendous effect on the memory usage of your programs; you don't have to manually delete objects (most of the time) but you can certainly have memory leaks.

Comment: @MichaelMyers Of course implementation choices effect memory usage, perhaps my comment was a little ambiguous. Regardless, using the Object wrapper types for the primitives is a very small memory overhead. And, if it is truly critical code where memory usage is really critical, then OP should be looking for [Primitive Collection(s)](http://pcj.sourceforge.net/). But, I expect that a modern JVM will not have any large difference(s) between primitive(s) and the object wrapper(s) - that's why there is an instance pool.

Answer (score 3):

Use ArrayList instead of a primitive array, then when you have all of the values in the ArrayList (which will grow) you can convert it to a primitive array like so:

```
 List<Character> l = new ArrayList<Character>();
 ...
 l.toArray();
```

Comment: you'll get an array of class "Character" which isnt a primitive, the primitive is "char"

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayList as it is automatically resized when you add or remove items.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListDemo {
public static void main(String args[]) {
  // create an array list
  ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
  System.out.println("Initial size of al: " + al.size());

  // add elements to the array list
  al.add("C");
  al.add("A");
  al.add("E");
  al.add("B");
  al.add("D");
  al.add("F");
  al.add(1, "A2");
  System.out.println("Size of al after additions: " + al.size());

  // display the array list
  System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al);
  // Remove elements from the array list
  al.remove("F");
  al.remove(2);
  System.out.println("Size of al after deletions: " + al.size());
  System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al);
  }
  }
```

Example taken from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm